# GAMS - Integer variable as index

Tags: gams-math

Let's consider a parameter `A` that takes a non-negative index and returns an integer. I would like to use the value of `A` in the optimization process, so I created an integer variable `B`. My goal is to use `B` as an **argument** for `A`, such that the optimizer can choose the *best index* to optimize the model.

The following code is an example of what I try to do:

```
parameter A(*)  "Parameter A"   /
    0 0,
    1 10,
    2 30,
    3 45,
    4 82
    /;

display A;

integer variable B  "Integer B, used as an index for parameter A";
free variable z     "Variable to maximize";

equations profit    "Profit";

profit..    z =e= A(B);

model m / all /;
solve m using MIP maximizing z;
```

When I try to compile it, GAMS returns the following error on the line where I define the equation `profit`:

```
Set expected
```

Is there a way to achieve what I try to do?

Comment: One can notice that the relationship between the index of `A` and its values is not **linear**, which means that we cannot iterate over `A` and multiply the value by `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use n binary variables instead of the integer variable (where just one can be 1 in the solution) and couple them to A. Could look like this:

```
Set i /0*4/;

parameter A(i)  "Parameter A"   /
    0 0,
    1 10,
    2 30,
    3 45,
    4 82
    /;

display A;

binary variable B(i);
free variable z     "Variable to maximize";

equations profit    "Profit"
          oneB;


profit..    z =e= sum(i,A(i)*B(i));
oneB..      sum(i,B(i)) =l= 1;

model m / all /;
solve m using MIP maximizing z;
```